# Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None trying to read PlaceableActor"

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to learn how to develop games with Unreal, and I am currently following this tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f98-D9T0Nk&ab_channel=TheGameDevChannel

Now I am at the part where I should be able to place items from the HUD to the world. I was able to replicate the HUD and its functionality of being able to choose buildings and placing them in the world. However, I am currently running into an error everytime I click on a building twice in succession (to deselect). But, if I select a different building after the first selection, I do not run into the error. e.g.

- Click item 1 > Click item 1 | error
- Click item 1 > Click item 2 | no error
- Click item 1 > Click item 2 > Click item 1 | no error
- Click item 2 > Click item 2 | error
- Click item 1 > Click item 2 > Click item 2 | error

Here is the error:
[image]

For context, here are screenshots of the blueprints affected:
[image]

[image]

I have tried checking the video's comments but no one has encountered said error. All I  know is that if I select on the same building twice, it runs into the error but I am not sure specifically why that happens. Please let me know what I can check to fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`PlaceableActor` did not exist at the moment those functions were called. Make sure you link `PlaceableActor` to an `IsValid` node before accessing it, in both your `Refresh Placeable Building` and `Update Placement` function to fix the errors.

Inside `Refresh Placeable Building`, double check that `SpawnActor` node did in fact return you a valid actor reference. `SpawnActor` could fail if the class is not valid.  Refer to your `PlaceableActorType` node (the purple node). You can right click on any blueprint node (with an exec pin) and select `Enable Breakpoint` so you can step through and inspect your code.

Inside `Update Placement`, before even executing a line trace, make sure that `Placeable Actor` exists by placing an `IsValid` node at the very start of the function before doing anything.